# What is the set containing only integers congruent to 89 modulo 17?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the set containing only integers congruent to 89 modulo 17

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you asking how to express this set with mathematical notation? Otherwise, there's nothing to say, really - the set containing the integers congruent to 89 modulo 17 is the set containing the integers congruent to 89 modulo 17.

Comment: $17k+4,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: That is the reason i am asking here, that is the question i got as it is

Comment: If that's the case, I suggest looking in the textbook for a similar example problem.  Sami's comment is one way of writing the answer, though it could be that, given the context of the problem, they're looking for a particular form.

Answer (score 2):

Since $89$ is congruent modulo $17$ to $4$, it is just $\{4,\ 4 \pm 17,\ 4\pm2\cdot17,\ 4\pm3\cdot17,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$89\equiv 4 \pmod {17}$$ So we want the set of all integers $x$ such that $\;x\equiv 89 \pmod{17}\iff x \equiv 4\pmod{17}$. That can be written in a number of ways, e.g.:

$$\{x\mid x\equiv 4 \pmod{17}\} \quad \text{or}\quad \{x \mid x = 17k + 4;\;\; k\in \mathbb Z\}$$

Comment: Getting back into Number Theory I see +1